# Can I run my appium code against iOS Real device from "windows" machine

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium, selendroid

Very simple straight forward question ,

Can I run my appium tests against any ios real device from my windows machine ?

All the R n D done , i am unable to reach a solution. 
please help.

An article would be of great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"tut mir leid" but no, if you want to run test on device with iOS you need OSX, cause ios-driver need this OS. On Windows you can only run Android and Windows Phone test.